# Ternary expression containing loose comparison in else branch yields unexpected result

Tags: php, comparison, operator-precedence, conditional-operator

Could someone help me with this code? On my website, there is no result.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id']) ? $product['valid2'] : ''==1) {
    echo "Yes";
} elseif (isset($_GET['id']) ? $product['valid2'] : ''==0) {
    echo "No";
}
```

Comment: What exactly you wanna do?

Comment: The last part of each ternary expression makes no sense. It should be a string, not an expression.

Comment: @Hamid Ahmadi In the database it is to be queried whether the id is assigned a 1 or 0. If the id has the value 0 the website should display "No" and if the value is 1 the website should display "Yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this function:

```
<?php
          
$v2 = isset($_GET['id']) ? $product['valid2'] : '';          
 
          
if ($v2==1) {
    echo "Yes";
} elseif ($v2==0) {
    echo "No";
}

?>
```

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it seems like you just want to check that the id is set or that it isn't assigned to 0.

This can be achieved using a simple check that it exists and then casting the value to Boolean. This will assign the value of > 0 to true and 0 to false.

```php
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id');
$idIsSet = (bool) $id;

if (!$idIsSet) {
    // Id is not set so do something to handle this.
    echo "No";
    die();
}

// The Id is set so you can do whatever you want with the Id.
echo "Yes";
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but how do I tell the function to take the entry "valid2" from the table with the respective id?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `$product['valid2']` ?
You can access this at any point during the if statement since it's in the same scope as your example?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Operator Precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) rules in php (which can change between different php versions), the loose "comparison" (`==`) enjoys a higher precedence than the "ternary" (`? :`).

This means that the loose comparison portion is evaluated before the `isset()` check.

It is also important to express that from php8 `''==0` evaluates as `false`, while in versions under php8 the same expression evaluates as `true`. Resource: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php

Boiled down, your `if` and `elseif` expressions are doing truthy/falsey checks.

1. As stated earlier, the loose comparison branch of the ternary expression is performed first.
2. If `isset($_GET['id'])` is true, the the value of `$product['valid2']` is evaluated as truthy/falsey.
3. If `isset($_GET['id'])` is false, the the value of the loose comparison is evaluated as truthy/falsey.

Without knowing your project intimately, it may be direct, correct, and readable to express the logic in the following manner.

```
echo isset($_GET['id']) && $product['valid2'] == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

This is not meant to duplicate your code's logic, but to improve it and ensure that you always receive a yes/no outcome.